# compiling c program into MATLAB format MAC OS X

Tags: macos, matlab, compilation, makefile, mex

Any help on my problem is appreciated...

I'm trying to run this program located in the sparsenet.tar.gz file at http://redwood.berkeley.edu/bruno/sparsenet/

There is a README that I try to follow but I can't seem to compile my cgf.c...

The first step I assume I did correctly (I'm pretty sure I am able to compile the libnrfopt.a).

But when I type "make" in the sparsenet directory, it says:
new-host-2:sparsenet user123$ make
mex -I./nrf -L./nrf -lnrfopt cgf.c
make: mex: No such file or directory
make: *** [cgf.mexmaci64] Error 1

I assume it means my terminal isn't recognizing Mex, can anyone point me to how that works? (Before you tell me I haven't done enough searching, I have...I just cant seem to find anything relevant...I have my command line options in Xcode running, GCC works, Mex -setup works)

By the way, I'm doing this in Terminal, not inside MATLAB. Doing it inside matlab by directly using Mex doesn't work for me either.

Also I've changed the mex extensions to a variety of choices including mexmac, mexmaci64, etc.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: if you run [`mexext`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mexext.html) it will tell you what extension is used for MEX-files on your platform

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get it to work (R2012b, OS X 10.8.4). The code is old though, looking at the dates on some of the files so I'm not surprised that you had issues. Following the README, first I performed `make libnrfopt.a` in the `nrf` folder using Terminal. Then, in the Matlab command window I used `cd` to move to the `sparsenet` folder and executed (the same command that that produced an error when you ran `make` from the Terminal):

```
mex -I./nrf -L./nrf -lnrfopt cgf.c
```

From here I was able to follow the README and run the example.

By the way, if you've never run `mex` in Matlab before, you may need to run `mex -setup` first. As you mentioned Xcode, I assume that you have the compiler you need.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I figured it out, in the makefile, I just needed to change the Mex = mex to the directory of mex.exec in my Matlab folder and change mext to maci64

Answer (score 0):

Yes I did put:

```
MEX = /Applications/MATLAB_R2012a.app/bin/mex
MEXT = mexmaci64
```

In case your mex setup is not alright, check mexopts.sh file and change
to `gcc-4.2` and `g++-4.2` in the CC options. I had these compilers. Other compilers
should work too.

In case more problems persist check out this: http://www.mathworks.nl/support/solutions/en/data/1-FR6LXJ/